# Using extern variables in visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, winapi

I tried defining

```
int GlobalVariable;
```

in FileA.cpp

and inside FileB.cpp, I tried to use GlobalVariable by declaring

```
extern int GlobalVariable;
```

but when I tried using GlobalVariable, I get 'GlobalVar' : undeclared identifier or some unresolved linking error, how do I go about making it work?

Comment: `GlobalVar` is not the same as `GlobalVariable`. It sounds like you made a typo in one of your source files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Without having your code)
Use this pattern:

### FileA.h

`extern int GlobalVariable;`

### FileA.cpp

`int GlobalVariable = 1000;`

Comment: so I just include FileA.h in whichever files which I want to use the global variable?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're defining a variable called `GlobalVariable` but in the error message the variable `GlobalVar` is mentioned. Make sure that you don't accidentally get the name wrong.

That being said, are you sure that `FileA.cpp` is compiled into whatever module `FileB.obj` (the object file generated from `FileB.cpp`) is built into?